# react native using foreach or map in fetch

Tags: react-native

i wanna use forEach or map function in the fetch. when i get result i need to map it for some reasons

```
const getfilters = async () => {
    await fetch(FILTER, requestOptionsFilters)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        result.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element)
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  };
```

```
that code wont work. 
{
"genders": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "erp_code": "1231231241",
            "name": "sadfsadf",
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "erp_code": "232312",
            "name": "asdfsadfsaf",
        }
],
"colors": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "erp_code": "234234",
            "name": "sadfsdf",
        }
]
}
```

this what get from API, i need to every items of genders and colors   "choosen":false

Comment: Can you explain your requirement, What does it mean choosen  : false?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the keys and a nested forEach/map.

```
const keys = Object.keys(result);
result.forEach(key => {
    const values = result[key]
    values.map(v => v.name)
})
```